# SmsManager: get message recipient phone number from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, smsmanager

There is how I send message to multiple recipient:

```
public void send(List<User> participants,
                 Func1<User, String> messageTextCallback,
                 Subscriber<SendingProgress> subscriber) { // TODO: throw error
    Observable<SendingProgress> observable = Observable.create(sub -> {
        String unequalSmsSentAction = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            private int totalToSend = participants.size();
            private int sentCounter = 0;

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        sub.onNext(
                                new SendingProgress(totalToSend, ++sentCounter)
                        );
                        if(sentCounter == totalToSend) {
                            sub.onCompleted();
                            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                        }
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        subscriber.onError(new SendSmsException());
                        sub.onCompleted();
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(unequalSmsSentAction));

        int totalToSend = participants.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < totalToSend; i++) {
            User participant = participants.get(i);
            logger.d(TAG, "sending to: " + participant.getUsername());
            PendingIntent sentPi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(unequalSmsSentAction), 0);
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                    participant.getPhones().get(0),
                    null,
                    messageTextCallback.call(participant),
                    sentPi,
                    null
            );
        }
    });

    observable
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .observeOn(mainThreadScheduler)
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

This code call `SmsManager.sendTextMessage(...)` for every User's phone number.

`BroadcastReceiver` receives every sent message and notifies subscriber about it. I want to get phone number of SMS recipient inside `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive` to pass it through `SendingProgress`.

**Is there any way to do this?**
**Should I send multiple SMSes synchronously?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this?

Step #1: Put the information that you want in an extra of your `unequalSmsSentAction` `Intent`

Step #2: Use a unique ID for each `PendingIntent` (the second parameter of your `getBroadcast()` call, where you have `0` -- replace it with a distinct value for each SMS)

Step #3: Read the information out of extra in the `Intent` delivered to your `BroadcastReceiver`

However, any app can listen for your `unequalSmsSentAction` broadcasts. Ideally, set the value of the extra in the `Intent` to be something *you* can use to find the phone number, but that cannot be used by any other app that receives those broadcasts.

> Should I send multiple SMSes synchronously?

AFAIK, you cannot send them synchronously.

Comment: By "simultaneously" I understand in turn order. For example: send a message only after a successful previous. But after your explanation, it's not needed. Thanks!

Comment: synchronously* @CommonsWare why should I use unique id(`requestCode`) for each `PendingIntent`?

Comment: @Alexandr: Because otherwise, you will just get the same `PendingIntent` back each time you call `getBroadcast()`. You need unique `PendingIntents` for your N simultaneous messages, as you have N extras (one per `Intent`). Extras themselves do not count for uniqueness, and otherwise all your `Intent` objects will be the same. Using the request code (2nd parameter to `getBroadcast()`) is the simplest way to get unique `PendingIntents`.